# AzureML Authentication for registering datasets using azureml.core.dataset

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am trying to register a data set programmatically using azurecli authentication

### What I tried

```
authentication = AzureCliAuthentication()

workspace = Workspace.from_config( "config.json"), auth=authentication)
store = Datastore.get(workspace, datastore_name)
path = [(store, filePath)]
dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(path=path)
```

I am logged in using `azure-cli`

```
az login
```

I am currently the owner of the datastore_name which is a gen2 datalake instance in the same subscription / region as the Azure ML workspace

### Question

- **I get an interactive login**  each time I get to the `Dataset.Tabular.from_` line. How can make it use the azure cli creds ?
- I plan to use the same python script as part of CI/CD pipeline azurecli task to register the datasets across multiple workspaces

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `cli_auth`

```py
from azureml.core.authentication import AzureCliAuthentication
cli_auth = AzureCliAuthentication()
ws = Workspace(
    subscription_id="your-sub-id",
    resource_group="your-resource-group-id",
    workspace_name="your-workspace-name",
    auth=cli_auth
)
```

Comment: That is what m using in the example in the question. What is the point that you are trying to make

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CLI command directly if you wish to use a script to register in Azure ML using Devops.

```
az ml dataset register [--file]
                       [--output-metadata-file]
                       [--path]
                       [--resource-group]
                       [--show-template]
                       [--skip-validation]
                       [--subscription-id]
                       [--workspace-name]
```